# CFBundleIdentifier does not exist on react-native

Tags: xcode, react-native

Easy bounty here for grabs. Does not necessarily require any react-native experience. Problem seems to be in open source code, which is available out there:

Updated xcode, and now when I try to run my react-native app by issuing following command: `react-native run-ios` I get an error:

> An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
> Failed to install the requested application
> An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
> Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
> Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
> error Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyAppName.app/Info.plist
> Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

> debug Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyAppName.app/Info.plist
> Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
> at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
> at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:634:13)
> at runOnSimulator (project-root-dir/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/runIOS/runIOS.js:181:45)

Before those errors, the command prints out info about successful build, and that it is about to install the build:

> info ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

> info Installing DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyAppName.app

So it seems the build is ok, but when it tries to install the app it fails?

Think I've tried "everything" I found from other questions with this similar error message, but nothing has worked for me.

Some specs:

react-native: 0.59.10 
react: 16.8.3 
xcode-version: Version 12.2 (12B45b)

I know there are similar questions on stackoverflow. But since none of the solutions provided there worked for me, and I wish to get it fixed, I made this separate question.

I do not know where the Info.plist file is that it tries to find: *DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyAppName.app/Info.plist*

Inside my ios folder, there is a folder called DerivedData, but inside that there are no folder with a name *Build*. So I think it might be looking from a wrong location?

UPDATE:

I've been able to pinpoint where the cli launch goes wrong:
https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/ba298d9c47af522f0377325bebc6c2075d41790a/packages/platform-ios/src/commands/runIOS/index.ts#L378

If I change that line `let buildPath = build/${scheme}/Build/Products/${configuration}-${device}/${appName}.app`

to -> `build/${scheme}/Build/Products/${configuration}-${device}/MyAppRealName.app`;

Then the dev launch works nicely, there's no problem. So it seems that getting the appName goes wrong. The appName is resolved here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/ba298d9c47af522f0377325bebc6c2075d41790a/packages/platform-ios/src/commands/runIOS/index.ts#L387

`const productNameMatch = /export FULL_PRODUCT_NAME="?(.+).app"?$/m.exec(buildOutput);`

I could do a post install npm script that just sets the name of the app correct and call it a day. But that's pretty hacky way. I wonder if there's an alternative that works better? I see that the runIOS file has been updated from the version that I have quite much, but the function getProductName still remains the same. So Im not sure if updating just the cli would work, or if it would even be possible, because it might require a newer react-native version, which is not an option for me right now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

newer version of `@react-native-community/cli` is not working on older version react-native because in newer version they have change `getProductName` to `getPlatformName`. for more detail you can read summary of this [PR](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/1326#issue-525991522)

## Solution

As a local workaround, patch the package by [patch-package](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/1326#issue-525991522) `node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js` and edited `getProductName` (lines 362–365) to read:

```js
 function getProductName(buildOutput) {
   const productNameMatch = /export FULL_PRODUCT_NAME\\?="?(.+).app"?$/m.exec(buildOutput);
   return productNameMatch ? productNameMatch[1].replace(/(?:\\(.))/g, '$1') : null;
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upgrade my react-native at the moment. But I might be able to upgrade just the cli, if it's compatible with the earlier version of react-native? What is the mimimun version of the react-native-community/cli that I should upgrade to?

Comment: yes but doesn't this command: `react-native upgrade` upgrade the whole react-native?

Comment: yes, you have to update react native or have to patch react native from this pull request. https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/commit/6526bdd834993267f6f3fed2f8521bf1a9b7b859

Comment: @VilleMiekk-oja you can directly change these 6 file into node_module https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/commit/6526bdd834993267f6f3fed2f8521bf1a9b7b859 and test if this work then you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

Comment: @VilleMiekk-oja can you tell me the version of react-native of your project?

Comment: Im sorry I can't update react native, that patch-package solution could become handy, even though I feel that too is a bit of a hack. react-native: 0.59.10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227345/discussion-between-ville-miekk-oja-and-muhammad-numan).

Comment: I think this is an incomplete solution. My project doesn't use `@react-native-community/cli` at all. I use `npx` to run RN commands from CLI. Nonetheless, I face this same issue when execution reaches the point to install the app on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

The result from `react-native run-ios` is:
`DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyAppName.app/Info.plist`

The correct should be:
`DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyAppRealName.app/Info.plist`

Then you could fix it by edit Xcode project as:

1. Open Product menu (status bar)
2. Scheme -> Edit Scheme
3. Under build section, add a post-action
4. In provide build settings from: choose target of your app
5. Use the script to copy `wrongname.app` to `realname.app`: `cp ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/real_name.app`

Or you can use symlinks instead of copying.

[image]

Comment: I don't think the post action of xcode is run at all if you just run `react-native run-ios`. So it kind of feels a hacky way to solve this, and I would have to run the app from xcode always. I would prefer something that is 1. not hacky, 2. is version controlled

Comment: did you give a try? It should be executed even if the build step is trigger from react-native's script

Comment: I still wonder what's the wrong-app-name? is it related to correct-app-name?

does your project contain any app Extension such as NotificationService extension, Share extension etc ...?

Comment: The wrong app name comes from this: `const appName = await buildProject(xcodeProject, selectedSimulator.udid, scheme, args.configuration, args.packager, args.verbose, args.port);` that function has line 254: `resolve(getProductName(buildOutput) || scheme);` It fails to find the product name with the function getProductName, so it defaults to the variable scheme. And the scheme variable value is wrong, it's not the name of the app. So the script won't find the Info.plist file because the path has the wrong app name

Comment: In Xcode 13.2.1, my path to `info.plist` is `../DerivedData/app-name/info.plist`. The `../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator` folder has no `info.plist`.